# Change position order in bootstrap when smaller screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the following pictures, when i make my screen smaller, naturally the second element goes below the first element, but i want to keep this order, 1,3,2.
That is because the third element should be below the first element.
Any way to acomplish this?

[image]

[image]

```
<%--MODULOS--%>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <label >Módulos</label>
                <select class="col-xs-12" multiple="multiple" id="cboModulos" name="cboModulos">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <%--RANGO DE FECHAS--%>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row rowPadding">

                <%--RANGO DE FECHAS--%>
                <div class="row">
                        <label class="paddingLabelBigDevice">Rango de Fechas</label>
                </div>

                <%--DESDE--%>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="txtFechaIni" class="col-md-2 removePadding lineHeightCampos35" >Desde</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fechaInicio" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" id="txtFechaIni" style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap;" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-format="['DD','MM','YYYY'],separator:'/'" data-beatpicker-extra="customOptionsDataPicker" data-beatpicker-module="today,clear" />
                </div>

                 <%--HASTA--%>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="txtFechaFin" class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 removePadding lineHeightCampos35">Hasta</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" name="FechaFin" id="txtFechaFin" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-format="['DD','MM','YYYY'],separator:'/'" data-beatpicker-extra="customOptionsDataPicker" data-beatpicker-module="today,clear" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <%--TIPOS DE DOCUMENTOS--%>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label id="lblTipoDoc">Seleccione un tipo de documento ...</label>
            <input id="txtIdTipoDoc" hidden="hidden" />
            <div id="divContenedorTipoDoc">
                <div id="divTiposDoc">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I can , but it will be confusing , is there a way to , just make the second block jump over the third block when medium or small size in bootstrap?

Comment: Have you looked at `push-` and `pull-`? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering pablito.aven is right--your rows and columns appear to be backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you join elements 1 and 3 as if they were a single element? That way you ensure that element 3 will **allways** be below element 1

```
<%--MODULOS--%>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <label >Módulos</label>
            <select class="col-xs-12" multiple="multiple" id="cboModulos" name="cboModulos">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label id="lblTipoDoc">Seleccione un tipo de documento ...</label>
            <input id="txtIdTipoDoc" hidden="hidden" />
            <div id="divContenedorTipoDoc">
                <div id="divTiposDoc">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <%--RANGO DE FECHAS--%>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row rowPadding">

            <%--RANGO DE FECHAS--%>
            <div class="row">
                    <label class="paddingLabelBigDevice">Rango de Fechas</label>
            </div>

            <%--DESDE--%>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="txtFechaIni" class="col-md-2 removePadding lineHeightCampos35" >Desde</label>
                <input type="text" name="fechaInicio" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" id="txtFechaIni" style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap;" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-format="['DD','MM','YYYY'],separator:'/'" data-beatpicker-extra="customOptionsDataPicker" data-beatpicker-module="today,clear" />
            </div>

             <%--HASTA--%>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="txtFechaFin" class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 removePadding lineHeightCampos35">Hasta</label>
                <input type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-md-10" name="FechaFin" id="txtFechaFin" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-format="['DD','MM','YYYY'],separator:'/'" data-beatpicker-extra="customOptionsDataPicker" data-beatpicker-module="today,clear" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or something like that.

Still, the proper way to build a bootstrap responsive grid is columns inside rows. You are doing it inverse, you have rows inside columns

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the the [bootstrap docs - column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) on how to do this.

One thing to keep in mind is that you will want to order elements on your page in the order they would  be laid out on a mobile device rather a desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as pablito.aven said, just by using two `col-md-6` container instead of three.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <row>A</row> 
  <row>C</row>
</div>  
<div class="col-md-6">B</div>
```

Otherwise if you want to keep them in seperate `col-md-6` container:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 first">A</div>  
 <div class="col-md-6 third">C</div> 
 <div class="col-md-6 second">B</div>
```

you may simply change the flexbox `order` attribute when you have a small screen.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .first{
     order: 1;
  }
  .second{
     order: 2;
  }
.third{
     order: 3;
  }
}
</style>
```